# Performance of DIckey Fuller test on nearly non-stationary series

Tags: r, time-series

when applying an (augmented) dickey fuller test on nearly non-stationary series (i.e. y_t = 0.97*y_{t-1} + e_t), the test should - from what I have read - perform quite poorly.

Yet when I apply this test to sufficiently long series (1000 time periods), i get very accurate results. When I perform the test on shorter series (100 time periods) the results are indeed poor.

Is there some way how to quantify the impact of sample size on DF test?

Or is my code wrong and the test should indeed perform poorly?

For T = 100 indeed poor performance:

```
# set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(3)

# number of repetitions
repetitions <- 100

# length of time series
time <- 100

# generate matrices of 100 nearly non stationary processes of length 100
unitRootMatrix <- NULL
nearlyNonStationaryMatrix <- NULL
for (i in 1:repetitions)
{
        # create vector of iid random errors
        errors2 <- rnorm(time, mean = 0, sd = 2)
        # create placeholders for processes
        temp2 <- rep(0, time + 1)
        for (j in 2:time)
        {
                temp2[j] = 0.95*temp2[j-1] + errors2[j - 1]
        }

        # bind recent process to previous processes
        nearlyNonStationaryMatrix <- cbind(nearlyNonStationaryMatrix, temp2)
}

# Augmented Dickey Fuller test
library(tseries)

temp <- NULL
pvals <- NULL
for (i in 1:ncol(nearlyNonStationaryMatrix))
{
        temp <- adf.test(nearlyNonStationaryMatrix[, i], )$p.value
        pvals <- c(pvals, temp)
}

sum(pvals > 0.1)
## [1] 83
sum(pvals > 0.05)
## [1] 90
sum(pvals > 0.01)
## [1] 98
```

for T = 1000 not so much:

```
# set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(3)

# number of repetitions
repetitions <- 100

# length of time series
time <- 1000

# generate matrices of 100 nearly non stationary processes of length 1000
unitRootMatrix <- NULL
nearlyNonStationaryMatrix <- NULL
for (i in 1:repetitions)
{
        # create vector of iid random errors
        errors2 <- rnorm(time, mean = 0, sd = 2)
        # create placeholders for processes
        temp2 <- rep(0, time + 1)
        for (j in 2:time)
        {
                temp2[j] = 0.95*temp2[j-1] + errors2[j - 1]
        }

        # bind recent process to previous processes
        nearlyNonStationaryMatrix <- cbind(nearlyNonStationaryMatrix, temp2)
}

# Augmented Dickey Fuller test
library(tseries)

temp <- NULL
pvals <- NULL
for (i in 1:ncol(nearlyNonStationaryMatrix))
{
        temp <- adf.test(nearlyNonStationaryMatrix[, i], )$p.value
        pvals <- c(pvals, temp)
}

sum(pvals > 0.1)
## [1] 0
sum(pvals > 0.05)
## [1] 0
sum(pvals > 0.01)
## [1] 5
```

Any thoughts, comments will be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Is there some easy way how to migrate the question to Cross Validated?

Comment: Now that it's been answered, just wait for high-rep users to vote to migrate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ADF is known to perform poorly against near-unit-root alternatives, it is, nevertheless, consistent.

```
set.seed(3)
library(tseries)
repetitions <- 10000
sim <- function(time){
  x <- replicate(repetitions , arima.sim(list(ar=0.95), time, innov=rnorm(time, mean=0, sd=2))) #near unit root
  pvals <- rep(0, repetitions)
  for (i in 1:ncol(x))
  {
    pvals[i] <- adf.test(x[, i], )$p.value
  }
  pvals
}
sample_sizes <- seq(100, 1000, by=100)
res <- lapply(sample_sizes, sim)
setNames(colSums(sapply(res, `<=`, 0.01))/repetitions, paste0("T=", sample_sizes))
#  T=100  T=200  T=300  T=400  T=500  T=600  T=700  T=800  T=900 T=1000 
# 0.0126 0.0319 0.0716 0.1538 0.2835 0.4207 0.6130 0.7400 0.8580 0.9322
```

This gives a power of the test as a function of the sample size.